# How do i secure a REST API with google authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-oauth, passport.js, single-page-application

I am trying to build a REST API with NodeJS and Passport, for a Single page javascript application, and i cannot figure out how to secure my REST API with Google OAuth, but i cannot figure out how to do it.

How would i do that?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-google

Answer (score 0):

At first You can use scopes to determine which client or user has which roles and  grant accesses. Secondly you should communicate with your api on ssl protocol.